# Does Google Analytics Content Drilldown Mix Pages With Directories in Results?

Tags: seo, google-analytics

I didn't set up this GA account and therefore don't have my custom setup that breaks the numbers up better.  I just want to verify I'm looking at this correctly. On the Content > Site Content > Content Drilldown page are they mixing directories with pages? Making this statements true:

1) If /products/ and /products were added together you would have an inaccurate number because /products are already included in the directory /products/?

2) In my example image, 1 and 2 are directories and 3 is a page?

Or does /products/ only include other directories... I'm so confused by this because If I click on /products/(the directory), /products(the page) isn't showing up on the list but other child directories and pages are?

Any insight would be much appreciated!!!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/d74Ms.jpg